# Table header appears twice at top of page

Tags: tables

The following minimal code demonstrates my problem.
(For me) the header appears twice on the table which
is placed at the top of page #2.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

ABC
\vspace{510pt} % Simulate a full first page.
\needspace{2\baselineskip} % Keep table from starting too soon.
\begin{longtable}{ l|l|l }
% The header will appear twice at the top of the table.
\hline \textbf{HD1} & \textbf{HD2} & \textbf{HD3} \endhead \hline
C1 & C2 & C3 \\ \hline
C1 & C2 & C3 \\ \hline
C1 & C2 & C3 \\ \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've encountered a conflict or incompatiblity between the `\needspace` macro and the `longtable` environment.

The manual of the `needspace` package notes that the space reserved by `\needspace` is "approximate". To get exact amounts of reserved space, use either `\Needspace` or `\Needspace*`.

Interestingly, if one replaces `\needspace{2\baselineskip}` in your MWE with either `\Needspace{2\baselineskip}` or `\Needspace*{2\baselineskip}`, the problem with the duplicate header on the second page goes away.

Comment: This shouldn't be a comment, it's a solution! There are far too many questions on TeX.SX that have an answer in the comments but show up amongst the 4206 unanswered questions on the site.

Comment: @Andrew - I don't think my posting amounts to a "full" solution. Maybe it's half-way between a comment and solution? If the OP likes it, he/she can upvote and/or accept it...

Comment: Thank you. I say full solution. Use of Needspace solved the problem. This is what scares me about TeX in general; I become dependent and then encounter a problem I can't solve. I'm glad this one could be solved.